# How to get alert for turning on location services?

Tags: android, geolocation

My application requires Location services to be turned on as same like Ola Cabs. I need to show a alert like this,

[image: Turn GPS Alert]

I don't want users to redirect to location settings page and make them come back to application. I hope the latest play services has this feature to turn on by clicking "Yes" in dialog. If anyone know about this let me know please.

I have searched in all the blogs they give some code to turn on with no user action but, this thing shown in image looks android's. I have seen in many applications using the same dialog with same text and link in it. If you have come across answer or comment it. Your ideas are most welcome but, don't close question saying invalid. It may not help you but someone else.

Comment: Marking as duplicate is easy, there is no proper answer for question. If you have found the proper answer for question you can share the question URL.

Comment: http://sanastasov.blogspot.in/2014/12/migrating-from-locationclient-to.html   Hope this might help, am trying it out. will let you know the result later.